# Android: how can i create a timer for 1 second

Tags: java, android

ok i am developing an andoird app which is the game simon, i encountered a problem that when i move from the menu to the game.
i want the game will play 3 sounds at the beggining of the game which is selected randomly
and the app to play them 1 after another in 1 sec delay, but the problem is the app before the game backgound is loaded the sounds all play at the same time.. shortly everything doesn't work and i am desprate. 
in order to use the buttons, i created a class called column which contains the button from the view and the sound it makes and use the method play to activate the sound and change the image.
the class Game for the logic of the game
here is the code:

Column Class:

```
package com.example.thegreatsimon;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Column {

ImageButton button;
SoundPool sound;
int soundId;    
int srcColor,lightColor;
Context con;
public Column(ImageButton button,Context con)
{
    sound=new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    this.button=button;
    switch (button.getId())
    {   
    case R.id.ibBlue:
    {
        soundId=sound.load(con,R.raw.a ,1);
        srcColor=R.drawable.blue;
        lightColor=R.drawable.lightblue;
    } break;
    case R.id.ibGreen:
    {
        soundId=sound.load(con,R.raw.b,1);
        srcColor=R.drawable.green;
        lightColor=R.drawable.lightgreen;
    } break;
    case R.id.ibRed:
    {
        soundId=sound.load(con,R.raw.c ,1);
        srcColor=R.drawable.red;
        lightColor=R.drawable.lightred;
    } break;
    case R.id.ibYellow:
    {
        soundId=sound.load(con,R.raw.d ,1);
        srcColor=R.drawable.yellow;
        lightColor=R.drawable.lightyellow;
    } break;
    }   
    button.setOnClickListener(new Listen());
}   

class Listen implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) 
    {
        play();
    }   
}

void play()
{
    sound.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)  ;
    button.setBackgroundResource(lightColor);
    Handler handler = new Handler();    
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            button.setBackgroundResource(srcColor);
        }
    }, 300);

}

}
```

The Game Class:

```
package com.example.thegreatsimon;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Game extends Activity {

Column bYellow,bRed,bGreen,bBlue;
SoundPool a=new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
int diff;
int life=3;
Random rand= new Random();
Handler hand = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    diff = Settings.difficulty;
    switch(diff)
    {
    case(0):
        setContentView(R.layout.gameeasy);
    break;
    case(1):
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
    bYellow=new Column((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibYellow),getApplicationContext());
    break;
    case(2):
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
    bYellow=new      Column((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibYellow),getApplicationContext());
    break;
    }
    bRed=new Column((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibRed),getApplicationContext());
    bGreen=new Column((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibGreen),getApplicationContext());
    bBlue=new Column((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibBlue),getApplicationContext());
    EasyGame();
}


public boolean EasyGame()
{
    int r;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    boolean proceed;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        r=rand.nextInt(3);
        switch(r)
        {
        case 0:
        {
            list.add(bRed);
            Sleep(bRed);                
        }break;
        case 1:
        {
            list.add(bGreen);
            Sleep(bGreen);
        }break;
        case 2:
        {
            list.add(bBlue);
            Sleep(bBlue);
        }break;
        }
    }
    proceed=UserPlay();

    /*for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        r=rand.nextInt(3);
        switch(r)
        {
        case 0:
            list.add(bRed);
            break;
        case 1:
            list.add(bGreen);
            break;
        case 2:
            list.add(bBlue);
            break;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
        {
            ((Column)list.get(j)).play();
            Sleep();
        }
        proceed=UserPlay();
    }*/

    return true;
}

public void MediumGame()
{

}
public void HardGame()
{

}



    public void Sleep(final Column c)
{
    Handler handler = new Handler();    
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
                public void run() {
                   c.play();
                }
            }, 1000);
}



public boolean UserPlay()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Use `Handler` to create a short delay.

Comment: can you be more specific? i tried to use handler in the function sleep that i created but it does nothing

Answer (score 6):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();    
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
            public void run() {
               //write your code here to be executed after 1 second
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: i tried what you did in the sleep method and got the sleep method to execute the play method of the column but still it plays all of the sounds at once.. i debbuged it and noticed that she handler is activating the play method only when my oncrate method is over

Comment: No. You have not done the same. You have created a new `Thread` which will obviously get executed after the current `Thread` that is your `UI Thread` gets over. What I did is different! It runs on the same `Thread`. Try it once and see if it makes the difference.

Comment: For more information on `Handler` go through [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) documentation.

Comment: naddy,
i meant that i changed the code according to what you said and it doesn't work.. i changed the method sleep and the method play in column look the change i made

Answer (score 2):

Look this code, i would have done so:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    TextView timerTextView;
    long startTime = 0;

    //runs without a timer by reposting this handler at the end of the runnable
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setText("start");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button b = (Button) v;
                if (b.getText().equals("stop")) {
                    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                    b.setText("start");
                } else {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
                    b.setText("stop");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: wow i really didn't understand what you meant here tried to combine this with my code and got lost :/