# How to stop this timer at 10 second?

Tags: android, timer

This code is run timer on android screen on button click. But I want to stop this timer at `10` second. I think we can access 'secs' variable value and kill `thread` at `10` second. But I don't know how to do this. Any other idea? So how to stop time at `10` second?

```
package com.example.image_changer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;
ImageView imageView1;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillisecond = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
     imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);


        }
    });
}


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    int secs;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timeInMillisecond = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()- startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff+timeInMillisecond;
        secs = (int)(updatedTime/1000);
        int mins = secs/60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int)(updatedTime % 10000);
        textView.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)+
                ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

        customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);



    }

};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I try these solutions:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

and in thread

```
int milliseconds = (int)(updatedTime % 10000);
        textView.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)+
                ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

        customHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
```

Then it count 1 to unlimited in Second(part)

---

Second solution try

If I try this on thread call then It not start counting.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

---

What I want - Timer watch run but it stop at exactly 10 second (only `second` part is matter for me)

---

When I try this, then It start counting from 10 to unlimited in second part.

```
       @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 10000);
        //customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

in thread

```
     timeInMillisecond = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()- startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff+timeInMillisecond;
        secs = (int)(updatedTime/1000);
        int mins = secs/60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int)(updatedTime % 10000);
        textView.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)+
                ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

        customHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029755/android-how-can-i-create-a-timer-for-1-second/20029854#20029854) link answer your question.

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper...did these given solutions helped you? you should reply back to those answers.

Comment: @HamidShatu Please check question again, I edit it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start count down timer  on click of a button and on finish remove the handler callback..

```
     new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
 }
}.start();
```